# Dropping all rows except ones with a certain criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I want to drop all rows that do not contain "PD-19-05-16" or "PD-19-06-01" in column "Document No." but after I ran the code it doesn't appear to make any changes.

Any advice on how to properly do this or correct the code would be greatly appreciated.

I tried using df.drop but have been running into lots of problems.

```py
df = df.drop(['Document No.'] != ['PD-19-05-16','PD-19-06-01'])
```

I expected this to work but got ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 4533 vs 2

Comment: It still shows values that arent the two doc no. that I need. For example, I'm getting PINV-0262 still showing up along with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
rows_to_keep = ["PD-19-05-16","PD-19-06-01"]
df.loc[df['Document No.'].isin(rows_to_keep)] 
#or if you need the inverse
df.loc[~df['Document No.'].isin(rows_to_keep)]
```

I don't think that's the correct use of drop tbf. I always find it easier to use `isin` to filter on a single column.

the `~` acts as negatory operator